# Multiple mail server from different provider for one domain is possible?

Tags: email, email-server, gmail, mailbox, e-mailrelay

I have searched in google before asking here. I got a mixed answer in google.

Can i have a multiple MX record from different mail providers?

Example,

**Zoho Mail**

```
user1@example.com 
user2@example.com
```

**Google Webmail**

```
user3@example.com
user4@example.com
```

**Rediffmail business**

```
user5@example.com
user6@example.com
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

MX records govern where external senders should route the messages for a particular domain, not a specific mailbox in that domain. So no, you can't use MX records for that.

But some mail providers do offer a configuration where, when they are the MX record for your domain example.com, they will accept all mail for `@example.com` and will:

- deliver locally the messages to mailboxes for the users/aliases created with them
- forward all messages for the users/aliases not created with them, in other words: for all unknown e-mail addresses, to another mail server.

That is a typical solution when some mailboxes are in the cloud and others on an on-premise mail server. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail

The challenge there is that all mail providers/servers you select will need to support that feature. Otherwise you run the risk that while for example user1@example.com (at zoho) can successfully send an e-mail to user5@example.com (at Rediffmail), the reply from user5 will fail with an error message "No mailbox for user1@example.com exists" because that mailbox does not exist with Rediffmail and Rediffmail is unaware that @example.com mailboxes can exist elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Shart answer: No. MX records are highlanders. There can only be one (target), not servers for domains.

A DNS zone for a MTA ISP with 300k mailboxes would potentially be VERY LARGE otherwise.